# Cant receive callback for google hangout button

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, google-hangouts

I have following hangout button js code, I expect callback when user clicks on hangout button. Its not working, is anything wrong ?

```
 gapi.hangout.render('hangout-button', {
  'render': 'createhangout',
  'topic': 'hangout_test',
  'invites': "[{'id': 'xxx@gmail.com', 'invite_type': 'EMAIL'}]",
  'initial_apps': [{
    'app_id': "google_app_id",
    'app_type': 'ROOM_APP',
    'start_data': {
      "user_id": "user_id",
      "user_email": "user_email",
      "token": "token",
      "callback_url": "abc.com/hooks/hangout",
      "host": "abc.com",
      "callback_data": "user_data"
    }
   }],
  'hangout_type': "normal",
  'widget_size': 130
});
```

Comment: probably a turbolink issue.

Comment: no I am not using turbolinks here. Do you know how to get hangout call url in case if user clicks button?

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly?

Comment: If you purpose is just to start a hangout call then there are several other simpler ways are out there to do it.

Comment: I want to save hangout url as soon as user starts it so that other users can join it on their views

Comment: Did my answer solved your issue?

Comment: I have not tried with following approach, I will give try and let you know

Answer (score 0):

You need to listen for the `onApiReady` event from Hanogut and then call `getHangoutUrl` on `gapi.hangout`. As explained in their documention here:
https://developers.google.com/+/hangouts/api/gapi.hangout.html#gapi.hangout.ApiReadyEvent

Adding the same code below:

```
  gapi.hangout.onApiReady.add(function(eventObj) {
    var hangoutUrl = gapi.hangout.getHangoutUrl();
       // After saving the url to a variable, pass it using an Ajax call
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: callbackUrl,
        success: successFunc,
        dataType: 'json',
        data: JSON.stringify({
                "hangoutUrl": hangoutUrl,
               })
      });
    });
```

Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30609147/2545197